# Override page.html.twig with custom module template

Tags: 8, theming

I want to override the page.html.twig template from a custom module. I know how to create a suggestion, but I would like it to find the template file in my custom module.

```
function promo_accc_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__promo__accc';
}
```

I'm not sure what I would need to do from here to get Drupal to look in /custom/modules/promo_accc/templates.